# Dataframe/Row Indexing for Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I was wondering how could I index datasets so that a row number from df1 can equal a different row number for df2? eg. row 1 in df 1 = row 3 in df2

[What I would like. (In this case: row 1 2011 = row 2 2016)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHL4U.png)

row 49:50 2011 b1 is the same as row 51:52 bt 2016 (both the same item, but different value in different years) but is sliced differently due to being in a different cell in 2016

I've been using `pd.concat` and `pd.Series` but still no success.

```
# slicing 2011 data (total)
b1 = df1.iloc[49:50, 6:7]         
m1 = df1.iloc[127:128, 6:7]   
a1 = df1.iloc[84:85, 6:7]  

data2011 = pd.concat([b1, m1, a1])

# slicing 2016 data (total)
bt = df2.iloc[51:52, 6:7]        
mt = df2.iloc[129:130, 6:7]   
at = df2.iloc[86:87, 6:7]     

data2016 = pd.concat([bt, mt, at])

data20112016 = pd.concat([data2011, data2016])

print(data20112016)
```

Output I'm getting:

[What I need to fix. (In this case : row 49 = row 51, so 11849 in the left column and 13500 in the right coloumn)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvqmH.png)

```
49                     11849
127                    22622
84                     13658
51                     13500
129                    25281
86                     18594
```

I would like to do a bar graph comparing b12011 to bt2016 and so on. meaning 42 = 51, 127 = 129 etc

```
#           Tot_x  Tot_y
# 49=51     11849  13500
# 127=129   22622  25281
# 84=86     13658  18594
```

I hope this clear things up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, add reproducible example and don't use screenshots.

Comment: Anthony, please, add expected output.

Comment: Done. Hope this makes everything more clear.

Comment: Updated my answer. It seems like, that is result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, here is solution using `merge`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([9337, 2953, 8184], index=[49, 127, 84], columns=['Tot'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([13500, 25281, 18594], index=[51, 129, 86], columns=['Tot'])

total_df = (df1.reset_index()
               .merge(df2.reset_index(), left_index=True, right_index=True))
```

And here is, using `concat`:

```
total_df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index()], axis=1)
```

And here is resulting barplot:

```
total_df.index = total_df['index_x'].astype(str) + '=' + total_df['index_y'].astype(str)
total_df
#          index_x  Tot_x  index_y  Tot_y
#   49=51       49   9337       51  13500
# 127=129      127   2953      129  25281
#   84=86       84   8184       86  18594

(total_df.drop(['index_x', 'index_y'], axis=1)
         .plot(kind='bar', rot=0))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway I can rename 49=51, 127=129 and 84=86. Thank you for the work so far much appreciated!

Comment: @Anthony.H Yes, you can change dataframe index like so `df.index = iterable`

Comment: I'm presuming I can't use the iloc[slicing] for the graph, I've got to hardcode the values in?

Comment: @Anthony.H Why you can't use slicing?

Comment: I'm referring to df1 = pd.DataFrame([9337, 2953, 8184], index=[49, 127, 84], columns=['Tot']) If I were to use slicing how would I accomodate for it? Refer to my slicing iloc data in my question. Cheers

Comment: @Anthony.H This dataframe was created only to show concept. `iloc` method will return `DataFrame` object, so you can apply methods from my answer to it. In terms of your question, just substitute `df1` and `df2` with `data2011` and `df2016` respectively